# How to build clojure application with ring server

Tags: jar, clojure, leiningen, ring

I got clojure project with ring library in it. This is project.clj:

```
(defproject words "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "Websocket handler for sessions"
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
  [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
  [aleph "0.3.0-alpha1"]
  [org.clojure/data.json "0.1.2"]
  [clj-redis "0.0.13-SNAPSHOT"]
  [compojure "0.6.2"]
  [clj-http "0.1.3"]]
:main words.play
;; Lein ring plugin will provide `lein ring server` functionality
;; (and some other relative to ring actions)
:plugins [[lein-ring "0.6.6"]]
:ring {:handler words.api/engine})
```

In development environment I run it with 2 commands:
    lein run server
    lein ring server
and it's works.

For production environment I want to minimize dependencies and build it into standalone jar with:

```
lein uberjar
```

How can I build it and run both of servers from one jar file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding to

```
:main words.play
```

I advice you to implement `-main` function in `words.play` something like

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (case (first args)
    "server1" (do (println "Starting server1") (start-server1))
    "server2" (do (println "Starting server2") (start-server2))
    (println "Enter server name, pls")))
```

Note, that `:gen-class` is necessary in namespace definition:

```
(ns words.play
    (:gen-class))
```

Implementation for `start-server1` and `start-server2` should depend on concrete frameworks: `(run-jetty ...)` for ring, `(start-http-server ...)` for aleph and so on (you can find more info in relative documentation).

Usage:

```
lein uberjar
## to start first server
java -jar my-project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar server1
## to start second one
java -jar my-project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar server2
```

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward approach is to pre-compile a class from a clojure source file that starts your application. Your `-main` function should ultimately call something like `(run-jetty #'engine {:port 8080})`.

Here's a good tutorial if you're not familiar with Clojure ahead-of-time compilation ("aot"):
http://kotka.de/blog/2010/02/gen-class_how_it_works_and_how_to_use_it.html

Then it's a matter of creating a shell script that launches your application with something like `java -cp you-uber.jar words.Main` or somesuch.

Note that the name of your "app launcher" class and final jar name are completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lein ring uberjar`. That would start the ring server. You could start the other server in the `:init` hook lein-ring provides.